# iOS XML with Attributes using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I want to parse an XML file and want to show the information in an TableView.

At first my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<machines>
<machine id="1" project="100" name="first" status="inactive" />
<machine id="115" project="101" name="second" status="alive" />
<machine id="252" project="456" name="etc" status="alive" />
</machines>
```

And here my starting Ocj-C code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:...{

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"machine"]){
    machine =[[Machines alloc]init];
}
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
[nodecontent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
NSLog(@"node content = %@",nodecontent);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:...
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"machine"]){
    machine.name=nodecontent;
    [tableArray addObject:machine];
    [machine release];
    machine = nil;
}
}
```

1. The NSLog for the nodecontent has no output.
2. How can i save the attibutes of an element? (got a class "Machines", here are id, project, name and status)

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `- (void)parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` gives you this information in a dictionary (see the attributes argument).  It is then up to you to save it off and do with it what you please.

For more information, see: [Parsing XML data with NSXMLParser](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) and [NSXMLParser Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)